# Configuration from Multiple Architecture

Tags: configuration, architecture, logic, vhdl

I am trying to learn Structural Modelling. So in my library code, I have only "AND_gate" entity with 2 architecture. and_3 is my first architecture for 3 input and and_4 is the second architecture for 4 input.
I am trying to use them as components but I have a problem with configuration.

and_4 is analyzed last so AND1 and AND2 work without problem because they are using and_4.

So my problem is when I try to draw RTL Schematic, my project doesn't use AND3 and AND4. I need to configure and_3 architecture for them.

```
...
architecture Structure of Structural_Modelling is

component AND_gate is
    Port ( INA1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA4 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           OA   : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

for AND3 : AND_gate use entity work.AND_gate(and_3);
for AND4 : AND_gate use entity work.AND_gate(and_3);

signal wire1, wire2, wire3, wire4 : STD_LOGIC;

begin
    AND1 : AND_gate port map (nx,y,t,nw,wire1);
    AND2 : AND_gate port map (x,y,nt,nw,wire2);
    AND3 : AND_gate port map (y,z,w,wire3);
    AND4 : AND_gate port map (ny,nz,nw,wire4);

end Structure;
```

This is my VHDL code for components library:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity AND_gate is
    Port ( INA1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           INA4 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           OA   : out STD_LOGIC);
end AND_gate;


architecture and_3 of AND_gate is
begin
    OA <= INA1 and INA2 and INA3 ;    -- 3 input AND gate
end and_3;


architecture and_4 of AND_gate is
begin
    OA <= INA1 and INA2 and INA3 and INA4 ;    -- 4 input AND gate
end and_4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is not possible to instantiate from multiple architectures of a single entity. Instead of that another entity for the second architecture can be used.

Comment: If I provide a default value for INA4 its works that's true. But that is not what I asked in the question. It would be still just using the last analyzed architecture. My problem was using 2 different architectures from the same entity as different components. In my AND_gate entity, there is a 3 input and gate with the name of and_3 which is not last analyzed. It still wouldn't be used as a component in that solution.

Comment: I am not talking about adding a default value to architecture. I was talking about adding a default value to instantiation as you suggested earlier.

Comment: See [structural_modelling.vhdl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bllnu8im4xram0n/structural_modelling.vhdl?dl=1) from a Dropbox. Has your Structure architecture modified to work as well as architecture entity_instantiation which also works and is Xilinx synthesis eligible. That's adding a default value to either the component declaration or entity declaration of AND_gate.